# How to get list of ARC conversion errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am dusting off a very old app and trying to get it cleaned up so I can re-submit it to the App Store.

It was written in Objective-C using manual reference counting. I tried using the automatic ARC conversion in Xcode (14.2).

It displays a message:

> Cannot Convert to Objective-C ARC

and

> Xcode found 22 issues that prevent conversion from proceeding.  Fix all ARC readiness issues and try again.

(I'm down to 22 after a couple of hours of work.)

However, the error messages show up in the issue navigator until I click on one to try to resolve it, and then they all disappear. Is there a way to view all the errors, including copying them to a text editor?

A related question: It looks like a good number of `@selector` declarations now throw errors in the ARC conversion because they are declaring selectors in a class defined in another file. (They appear to be listed as errors in the ARC conversion preview, but only warnings if I build the project, which is odd.) What is the Objective-C syntax for defining a selector in another class? In swift it's just ClassName.selector, but what is it in Objective-C? I've tried searching the docs and googling it, but haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: Is the selector visible? Is the selector in the header of the class and is the header included?

Comment: Is Show live Issues switched on? What is reventing you from copying the isssues? Doesn't select all, Copy work? Have you tried Oen Build Log in the context menu?

Comment: For the ARC conversion feature, the list of errors is very squirrely. It shows the errors specific to ARC conversion for a few seconds; sometimes it clears the first batch and shows another batch, and then all the conversion errors go away and it reverts to showing normal build warnings. It's maddening, and all but impossible to use.

Comment: I do in fact have "show live issues" checked.

Comment: @Willeke, what do you mean "is the selector visible"? Visible where? The compiler can't find the selector, so it just flags it as being unknown selectors. In Swift, there is a straightforward syntax for qualifying a selector by the class it belongs to, but I am not aware of a way to do that in Objective-C. (My Objective-C has gotten very rusty.)

Comment: I have "show live issues" unchecked and the ARC errors don't disappear.

Comment: Is the selector declared in the header file of the class it belongs to and is this header file imported in the file with the error?

Comment: @willeke, there are a bunch of selectors with the same problem. I just checked one of them, and sure enough it is declared in the header of the class that defines it and the .m file that references it imports that header.

Comment: I managed to slog through all the conversion warnings by quickly taking a screen-shot while they were on screen and then fixing them one by one. (For the selector errors I used `NSSelectorFromString:` to get around them.) Now that I have finished the ARC conversion, I just tried, and I am able to go back to `@selector()` syntax and it works. The ARC converter seems to not have been able to find the functions in their owning classes but the normal compiler on an ARC project does.

Comment: I'm thinking Apple has not put much effort into maintaining the ARC converter and it's gotten buggy. I haven't tried to use it myself in a lot of years.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252641/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-willeke).

Comment: I tried to convert an old project to ARC and don't have issues with disappearing errors or selectors. It's easier to do the ARC and new deployment target steps one by one. Switch "show live issues" off when fixing the ARC errors. Post a [mre] if you want help with the selectors.